# Signed angle between 2 vectors?

Tags: linear-algebra, trigonometry, vector-spaces

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2150050/finding-signed-angle-between-vectors

on this link I found the following formula:

```
signed_angle = atan2(b.y,b.x) - atan2(a.y,a.x)
```

or I can rewrite it as:

```
atan2(y, x) = atan(y / x)

vectors:
a = {x1, y1}
b = {x2, y2}

signed_angle = atan(y2 / x2) - atan(y1 / x1)
```

And it doesn't work properly for example when:

```
a = {-1, 0} and b = {1, 0}
```

Additionally I know a direction from first angle to a second one (clockwise or counterclockwise) but I don't know how to apply it to a first formula.

How to solve this issue?

Comment: What does not work properly? IMO the angle from $a$ to $b$ is $-\frac{\pi}{2}$. You have $\textrm{atan2(b.y,b.x)} = \frac{\pi}{2}$,  $\textrm{atan2(a.y,a.x)} = \pi,$ so the difference is also $-\frac{\pi}{2}$

Comment: omg. the angle between a and b is Pi or -Pi. And this formula returns one predefined value only

Comment: How do you get Pi or -Pi? In the complex plane (-1,0) is -1 and (0,1) is i. This is a right angle, i.e. Pi/2. Going from a to b is Pi/2 clockwise which is -Pi/2 counter-clockwise and thus the standard mathemical value.

Comment: I forgot that tan is a periodic function. So this formula is not appropriate at all.

Comment: The formula is valid (it is just the difference to the arg values of the complex numbers from the 2-d vectors). Why to you think the forgotten periodicity of tan makes it inappropriate?

Comment: because I need to draw a sector. I have vA = {-0.5, 0} and vB = {0, -0.5} I calculate angles with vC = {0, 1}. And this formula shows me angleAC = -Pi and angleBC = Pi / 2, but I need angleAC = Pi because the direction is clockwise.

Comment: Again: An angle of Pi clockwise is a mathematical angle of -Pi, and the formula is correct once again. But let's stop this fruitluss commenting.

Comment: SORRY, a mistake was in an issue description. Vectors are (-1, 0) and (1, 0)

Comment: @user2083364 Take a bit more time to check your assumptions. Your assumption `atan2(y, x) = atan(y / x)` is false. `atan2` does not have singularities as `atan` (when `x=0`) has, moreover, it preserves the quadrant information, while the quadrant is lost in `atan`, for example `atan2(1,1)` is not equal to `atan2(-1,-1)`, while in `atan` produce the same result.

Answer (score 2):

I have dealt with the same problem.

Let us say that you have the vectors u = (u1, u2), v = (v1, v2) in the plane. What would be a good definition of a signed angle between the vectors u and v? One possible definition is to define it by the rotation angle that applied to vector u results in a vector with same direction and sense of v.

For example, if u = (1, 1) and v = (-1, 1), then the angle theta(u, v) would be + pi/2 (90 degrees), since if rotating u counterclockwise 90 degrees you get v. Observe that theta(v,u) is -pi/2, since you need to rotate v 90 degrees clockwise to obtain u.

Observe also that you could also rotate u by -3*pi/2 (-270 degrees) to get v. So, in order to make the definition unique, you should pick up the angle that lies in (-pi, pi]. Observe that for the vectors u = c(1,1) and v = (-1,-1), the angle could be +pi (+180) or -pi (-180), so you need to choose one, e.g., +pi.

In general, we have the following properties of the theta function:

1. theta(u,v) = -theta(v,u)
2. theta(-u, v) = theta(u,v) - pi
3. theta(u,-v) = theta(u,v) - pi

One R script to implement that function using atan2 function is given below:

```
theta <- function(u, v) {
    # u, v: matrices of bivariate vectors with 2 columns
    u <- matrix(u, ncol = 2)
    v <- matrix(v, ncol = 2)
    if (nrow(u) != nrow(v)) stop("u and v must have the same number of 
                                  rows")
    result <- as.numeric(atan2(v[,2], v[,1]) - atan2(u[,2], u[,1]))
    ind1 <- which(result > pi)
    ind2 <- which(result <= -pi)
    result[ind1] <- result[ind1] - 2*pi
    result[ind2] <- result[ind2] + 2*pi
    return(result) 
} # end-function
```

I hope this helps,

Luis Ernesto

Answer (score 1):

My current solution:

```
angleAC = ... (angle of vector A with Ox)
angleBC = ... (angle of vector B with Ox)
dangle = (angleBC - angleAC) / n (n is a number enough to split a big angle to oblique angles)
```

if (dangle > 0 and clockwise) or (dangle < 0 and counterclockwise) then check angleAC and angleBC. If they are less than 0 then add 2 * Pi to them.

This action looks strange but it really allows to get angle from A to B according to clockwise/counterclockwise direction